# Chevrolet S10 won't crank

Tags: battery, chevrolet, alternator, starter

I have a 2002 S10 that won't start. I had work done to repair an oil leak, drove it home, and it died. Thought it was maybe the battery, which had, in fact failed. I replaced the battery, and it ran for about a day and a half (less than 10 miles driven), but now it won't crank again. It unlocked with the remote, made a quick chime, and then went silent. It makes no noise whatsoever when the key is turned, and no lights come on at all. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your new battery is also flat which, in my mind, points to a fault with the alternator.  Try charging the battery or jump starting the vehicle, if this works then have the output of the alternator tested.

Comment: It could also be loose or corroded cables - was this checked and double-checked when putting in the new battery?

Comment: @mike65535 very true, improperly fitting or corroded battery terminals could certainly cause this type of behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an electrical meter?  What is the voltage across the battery?  Won't crank and won't start are 2 different things.  If it won't crank, the starter is not getting enough current to turn the engine over.  This could be a bad solenoid, or a electrical connection issue to the battery, or a discharged battery.  (Other strange causes: starter relay, fuse, ignition switch, wiring issue)  Which problem do you have?  A meter will tell you.  Without it, you will be playing a guessing game.  They are [cheap](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=B001O1X65A).